# How to make nc listen for remote connections

Tags: linux, networking, nc

I'm trying to listen for a remote connection but `nc` keeps giving me this error:

```
Error: Couldn't setup listening socket (err=-3)
```

This is the command I used:

```
nc -lvnp port_number -s my_public_ip
```

Comment: There are a number of implementations of `nc`, which one are you using?

Comment: Which port number is this, and are you root or a non-privileged user? Alternatively, could the port be in use by another process?

Comment: By the way, some (all?) versions of netcat don't allow to combine -l with -p.

Comment: i want to use nc in listening mode i'm expecting a remote connection outside my local network , i checked the port it's not in use by any other process and my nc version allow to combine -l with -p it works just fine on localhost without the -s flag

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a remote connection outside your local network, then you need to configure port forwarding in your router, so the external port is forwarded to your machine behind NAT. Once you punch that hole, you can use nc. For example, if you configure WAN_IP:5600 forwarded to your local IP behind NAT, port 5600, then something like this shall work:

`[host]$ nc -q1 -l -p 5600
[outside machine]$ echo 1 | nc -w1 your_public_ip 5600`


Specifying "-s IP" is useless in your case, because that is typically localhost or your local IP behind NAT. What you really want is your public IP, not some local source address.

Also, make sure you are not blocking the connection within your local firewall:

`sudo ufw status verbose`

Your router shall also be configured not to block the connection.